Calculate SE using CI
How I could to calculate Standard Error (SE) using only Hazard Ration plus Confidence Interval? Is it possible? Thanks
I dont see how do it with out total number of sample, but, there app Review Manager ($$) of Cochrane that do it! Screenshot
